# Remove pagination links under comments in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I have embedded a view in node--mytype.tpl.php but the pagination links from the view also appear under the comments.

I have looked everywhere but can't find a way to change this.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The "pager id" from the views pager was conflicting with the comment pager is. I changed the "pager id" of the view to 1 and it worked.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Embedding a view should not affect comments display. Have you tried taking a look at your Content Type edit page and see the *Comments per page* setting?

Comment: That's what i thought too but for some reason it was. I couldn't figure out why. The problem only appeared when pagination was required for comments i.e. more that 10 (I had set it to 10 specifically to test this issue).